# No registra la contraseña para loguear pero manda a donde debiera ir si estuviera bien

Tags: php, mysqli

Buenas tardes!

/*/[hay rebelión en casa, sale y no piensa comprar sanguchitos de miga la venganza será TERRIBLE]*

Estoy revisando y cuando reviso soy un poquito extrema. Esto no funciona. 
Casos:

a)username (bien) clave (bien) grupo (mal) Excelente! me rebota

b)username (mal) clave (bien) grupo (bien/mal) Bien, me rebota

c)username (bien) **clave** (bien o **mal**) grupo (bien) me manda a donde solo debería mandarme si la clave estuviese bien.

Tabla 98 campos: 98idusr,  98user, 98clave, 98grupo (donde user es el usuario, clave es el password y grupo es al grupo de afinidad al que pertenece, cada uno tiene un menú específico.)

Conclusión creo que no esta revisando que la clave tenga algo que ver con el usuario, es más creo que ni la verifica como algo existente, como en el caso del grupo que dice al menos si el grupo existe.

En fin soy toda ojitos!

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
require('900encab.html');
require('901musr.html');
if(isset($_POST['bt-011']))
{
    include('990conn.php');
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $clave = $_POST['clave'];

    $hash = password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    if (password_verify($clave, $hash)) {
        echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';

    $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
    $error = '';
    $sql011 = "SELECT 98idusr, 98user, 98clave, 98grupo FROM $t98 WHERE 98user = '$username' AND 98grupo = '$grupo'";
    $res011 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql011);
    $rows=$res011->num_rows;
    if ($rows > 0) {
        $rw011 = $res011->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['98idusr'] = $rw011['98idusr'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $rw011['username'];
        $_SESSION['clave'] = $rw011['clave'];
        $_SESSION['grupo'] = $rw011['grupo'];
        $error= "El nombre de usuario o clave es incorrecto, Por favor vuelva a intentarlo";
        if ($grupo)
        {
            switch ($grupo)
            {
                case '1':   header('location: Index1.php');  break;
                case '2':   header('location: Index2.php');  break;
                case '3':   header('location: Index3.php');  break;
                case '4':   header('location: Index4.php');  break;
                case '5':   header('location: Index5.php');  break;
                case '6':   header('location: Index6.php');  break;
                default:    header('location: Index.html');  break;}
            }
        }else{
            echo "La variable grupo no tiene datos"; (otra cosa que ni debiera estar porque siempre el grupo tiene un dato al menos por defecto, es un select)
        }
    }else{
        echo "No se encontraron registros.$username $pass $clave $grupo "; //(esto estaría bien si me quedo en la misma pagina pero si es exitosa la conexion me debiera mandar a un Index y no mostrarlo, considerenlo un var_dump después que funcione bien voy a eliminar esas variables)
    }
    } else {
        echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
    }
//}else{ (comentado porque no me interesa saber que no hay datos en el POST si todavía no empecé a ponerlos)
//    echo "No hay datos en el POST";
//}
?>
```

Comment: El echo `La variable grupo no tiene datos"; (otra cosa que n` te falta cerrarlo correctamente. Por favor [edit] tu pregunta y explica la relación entre `username, clave y grupo`. Saludos. PSDT: Revisa [cómo elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Creo que está bien cerrada, el comentario entre parentesis obvialo para el código ¡por favor! 
Ya edité la pregunta y expliqué lo que solicitaste. 
Gracias. Buen fin de semana @MauricioAriasOlave

Comment: Silvia, ¿El valor de `98grupo` en el SELECT lo envías como nombre de grupo o como un número?. Respecto al comentario que hice, noté que en realidad es un comentario, pero no lo cerraste bien. Si es posible, por favor edita tu pregunta agregando ejemplos de qué datos tienes en la tabla y qué datos estás usando en el SELECT. El `if ($grupo)` yo lo cambiaría por algo mas consistente como "validar si esa variable está vacía" Gracias y buen fin de semana para tí tambien.

Comment: se envia como se registra en la bd, número tal como aparece luego en el switch.  iduser (num) user (txt) clave (hash pass en bd, pero ingresa clave plana y hay que compararla) va foto de tabla

Comment: 98idusr 98user 98clave   98grupo
20  sbg         barb       5
22  trompita trompi 3

fue más facil copiar un pedazo de la tabla que subir la foto

Comment: Silvia, los comentarios son temporales, es mejor que por favor, la información útil vaya en el cuerpo de la pregunta (por ejemplo, la información que colocaste de ejemplo en tu comentario anterior). Viendo mas de cerca el código veo esta línea: `$_SESSION['clave'] = $rw011['clave'];` creo que deberías validarla para saber si efectivamente la clave (obtenida de la sesión) y la clave (obtenida de la consulta) son iguales; si no es así, ejecuta esta línea: `header('location: Index.html');` y mira, dice `$rw011['clave'];`, ¿no debería ser `$rw011['98clave'];`?

Comment: probablemente, me fijo y te contesto

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67084/discussion-between-mauricio-arias-olave-and-silvia-gaviota-garcia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras largos días y algo de investigación rehice toda la página de logueo + redirección

Para el logueo hice copia fiel del original que aqui les pego, fácil de entender o  por lo menos lo fue para mí.

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php

para la redireción utilicé como base la página welcome que proporciona el mismo link y que ahora les pego. Advertencia: Funciona. Se aceptan críticas y mejoras de código debido a mi natural falta de elegancia al respecto. Muchas gracias a todos y especialmente a @Mauricio Arias Olave que me toleró en el chat por cerca de dos horas.

El error fundamental estaba en el modo en el que hacía sucesivamente password hash y password verify ESO NO SE HACE!!!

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
include('990-conn.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) ;
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
            $sql011 = "SELECT 98idusr, 98user, 98grupo FROM 98usr WHERE 98user = '$username' ";
            $res011 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql011);
            $rows=$res011->num_rows;
                if ($rows > 0) 
{ //variables de session
                    $rw011 = $res011->fetch_assoc();
                    $idusr = $rw011['98idusr'];
                    $username = $rw011['98user'];
                    $grupo = $rw011['98grupo'];
                    if ($grupo) { //comienzo switch
                        switch ($grupo) { //comienzo case
                            case '1':   header('location: Index1.php');   break;
                            case '2':   header('location: Index2.php');   break;
                            case '3':   header('location: Index3.php');   break;
                            case '4':   header('location: Index4.php');   break;
                            case '5':   header('location: Index5.php');   break;
                            case '6':   header('location: Index6.php');   break;
                            default:    header('location: Index.html');   break;
} //fin case
} //fin switch
} //fin variables
$res011->free();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Espero que les sirva!

Answer (score 0):

Mira como he organizado el código. Creo que el problema que tienes con el código es mas un problema de organización.

Revisa y me cuentas para realizar los ajustes.

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();
require('900encab.html');
require('901musr.html');

if (isset($_POST['bt-011'])) {

    include('990conn.php');
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $clave = $_POST['clave'];

    $hash = password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    if (password_verify($clave, $hash)) {
        echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';

        $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
        $error = '';
        $sql011 = "SELECT 98idusr, 98user, 98clave, 98grupo FROM $t98 WHERE 98user = '$username' AND 98grupo = '$grupo'";
        $res011 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql011);

        $rows = $res011->num_rows;

        if ($rows > 0) {

            $rw011 = $res011->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['98idusr'] = $rw011['98idusr'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $rw011['username'];
            $_SESSION['clave'] = $rw011['clave'];
            $_SESSION['grupo'] = $rw011['grupo'];

            if ($grupo) {
                switch ($grupo) {
                    case '1':
                        header('location: Index1.php');
                        break;

                    case '2':
                        header('location: Index2.php');
                        break;

                    case '3':
                        header('location: Index3.php');
                        break;

                    case '4':
                        header('location: Index4.php');
                        break;

                    case '5':
                        header('location: Index5.php');
                        break;

                    case '6':
                        header('location: Index6.php');
                        break;

                    default:
                        header('location: Index.html');
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                echo "La variable grupo no tiene datos";
            }
        } else {
            $error = "El nombre de usuario o clave es incorrecto, Por favor vuelva a intentarlo";
            echo "No se encontraron registros.$username $pass $clave $grupo " . $error;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
    }
} else {
    echo '¿Aquí qué deberías mostrar?';
}
?>
```

Comment: ¡Un obsesivo de la prolijidad igual que yo! :D  Me atrevo entonces a señalarte que te faltó un espacio en `if(isset`  xD

Comment: @CJNimes ya lo he corregido usando NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 - combinación `Alt + shift + f` :)